# Append objects equal to the sum of every element in an array

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an array: `circleArray = [1, 4, 2]`. And now I want to generate circles. The **index** refers to the **row** I want them to be displayed. The **value of each element** refers to the **number of circles** in the specific row.

That's how it should look like:

[image]

That's what I've tried:

```js
// Circle Attributes
var nodeRadius = 20;
var xStart = 200, yStart = 50;
var xMargin = 50, yMargin = 50;

var circleArray = [1, 4, 2];

// SVG Viewport
var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
                      .append("svg")
                      .attr("width", 300)
                      .attr("height", 600);

// Append Circles                      
var circle = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
              .data("circleArray")
              .enter()
              .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function(d) { return d * xMargin + xStart; })
                .attr("cy", function(d,i) { return i * yMargin + yStart; })
                .attr("r", 20);
```

```html
<body></body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

This whole thing doesn't make much sense yet, but my biggest concern is **how to process the data of the array in a way that the value of the elements represent the number of circles and the index the row**. Usually all I managed to do was appending circles equal to the array length and completely ignoring the value of the element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most simple way to do this is using your data array to append groups...

```
var group = svgContainer.selectAll(null)
  .data(circleArray)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  //etc...
```

... and then, for each group, use the value of the datum to create **another array** with the number of the circles you want for each row:

```
var circles = group.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d3.range(d)
  })
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  //etc...
```

In this case, we get the datum of each group...

```
.data(function(d) {
    return d3.range(d)
})
```

... and pass it to `d3.range()`, which creates these arrays:

- `[0]`
- `[0, 1, 2, 3]`
- `[0, 1]`

Those values are used by the circles' selection. Of course the values themselves don't matter, just the length of each array.

Here is the demo (full of magic numbers, change them accordingly):

```js
// Circle Attributes
var nodeRadius = 20;

var circleArray = [1, 4, 2];

// SVG Viewport
var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 300);

var group = svgContainer.selectAll(null)
  .data(circleArray)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + (300 / 2 - ((d / 2) * 50)) + "," + (50 + 50 * i) + ")";
  });

var circles = group.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d3.range(d)
  })
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d * 50;
  })
  .attr("r", nodeRadius)
  .style("fill", "red");
```

```html
<body></body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

PS: not related to your problem, but `.data("circleArray")` is wrong. it should be `.data(circleArray)`.